# Is there a way to insert a token into null values in a dataframe that can be ignored?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm not sure how to word it correctly, so I'll describe it here. I'm trying to predict from some data whether or not it will be Yes/No using scikit.

I currently have 4 dataframes each representing a different year. The older ones have a few columns that are empty but are filled in the more modern ones. The type of data for these columns qualitative - large, small, primary, assistant. Basically you can't calculate the data. I can't run the code with Null values so I want to introduce a token that can be ignored in training or something that can accomplish the same goal.

For things that I have tried, I couldn't find anything online that was similar to my problem. I'm fairly new to machine learning so I'm not familiar with the terms.

The way I'll use the data is like this

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
def encode_features(df_train, df_test,column):

    features = column;
    df_combined = pd.concat([pub2016[features], pub2017[features], pub2018[features], pub2015[features]])

    for feature in features:
        le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
        le = le.fit(df_combined[feature])
        df_train[feature] = le.transform(df_train[feature])
        df_test[feature] = le.transform(df_test[feature])
    return df_train, df_test

traindf, testdf = encode_features(traindf, testdf,columnnames)
traindf.head()

#splitting into training sets code
#using RandomForestClassifier
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why won't you just slice for existing data e.g. `df_combined[~df_combined.feature.isna()][feature]`?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand correctly but it seems like you want to remove missing data.

Comment: Ohh, my wording might be bad. I want to process the missing data as well but I can't because its a Null value. I've been told by others that putting in random words as placeholders is bad, so I've been looking for something that I could put in that would let it be processed but be ignored?

Comment: Is it possible that you share at least a representation of the DataFrames ? I agree with @AlexFish in your question you ask the null values to be ignored so it seems you want them to be removed. Basically in a Machin Learning problem you can handle missing data by removing them or by replacing them. You can replace the missing data by different technics such as taking the mean, the most present class, estimate the density based on your present data and use Monte carlo algorithms, or just put a token as you said which creates a new category for missing data.

Answer (score 0):

The core of your question is a common one - "how do I deal with missing values?" As others have shouted long and loud from the rooftops - do *not* simply replace values with a "dummy" or "token" value (like -9999). This will hurt you (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/225175/why-do-some-people-use-999-or-9999-to-replace-missing-values). If you do decide to add an out-of-domain token (like the most negative number you can represent), be very careful normalizing or standardizing your data. You should also add another column specifying which values are filled with this token and which are observed (especially useful for decision trees).

It sounds like you're performing a binary classification, meaning you might be using a logistic regression or decision tree to handle this classification. The technique you are using determines the correct way to filter out missing data. But here are some principles to consider:

1) Does this feature matter all that much? If it doesn't matter very much for the years for which you have it, consider dropping it entirely. If it does matter, decide on a strategy for filling the missing values.

2) If you must fill/impute the values, can you replace it with the mean or median? Generally, this method assumes that the your data is stable enough over the span of your sample (i.e., is stationary with respect to time or some other dimension of your data) that missing values can simply be described by the central tendency. However stationarity is a big assumption, and replacing all of these values will definitely change your overall distribution.

3) If you don't want to use a broad approach like mean, median, or modal fill, consider imputing the missing values. Scikit-learn has many methods for imputing missing values, and as others have suggested you can use a technique like Monte Carlo simulation to impute missing data. This is adding a chunk of variance to your data, though, as now you have the error from imputing these missing values (and their possibly different distribution WRT the real values) in place.

In general, two things suggest to me that you should drop this feature entirely unless it's extremely predictive. First, you have a lot of missing data. Second, your missing data is structured - it's not randomly selected. You're missing data for years in the beginning of your training set, but not years in the end. You could have interactions between the feature with missing data and other variables (especially time) that make inferring the value of that feature earlier in time problematic. For instance, consider if this feature was standardized test scores of students. What if the scoring method changed during the time period for which you have missing data? Without the ability to translate between the two scoring methods, you will generate inappropriate values. As another example, what if this feature was average gas mileage? If the country this data was sampled from imposed some new requirement for minimum gas mileage during the period for which you have missing data, you would expect a floor shift that might change the distribution of this feature substantially, essentially destroying your ability to impute it.

Suffice to say that if it were me, and this feature were not absolutely critical, I would probably drop it. If you can't drop it, I would consider making your predictions (and fitting your models) only to years for which you have this data.

The uncomfortable truth of machine learning is that sometimes the data just isn't there.